# Adjusting height of nested ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a layout: ScrollView -> RelativeLayout -> TableLayout -> TableRow -> ListView. I have no idea how I can change height of ListView according to content. I have an adapter but the ListView's height doesn't change. It is not scrollable too, but it doesn't need to be. I have read that using nested ListView is a bad practise, but I cannot see any solution, because the source of image in the Column0 depends on multiple variables (it doesn't need an adapter). I cannot use a LinearLayout instead of ListView because I need an adapter.

Example:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1000dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
<TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#000000" 
            android:showDividers="middle" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button0"
                    android:layout_width="100sp"
                    android:layout_height="100sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView0"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    >
```

What I want to have:
[The conception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQSl7.jpg)

Comment: You seem to be using `match_parent` as the height of your `ListView`...

Comment: Nothing changes if I use match_parent or wrap_content as the height of my ListView or TableRow. I can only set the height manually.

Comment: @adamsc have a look here, http://blog.lovelyhq.com/setting-listview-height-depending-on-the-items/

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal It works, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, doing this is a bad idea.

You can probably write a custom view extending something like a `LinearLayout`, with support for populating views in it using adapters. Something like this: [NestableListView](https://github.com/tfKamran/nestable-list-view/blob/master/nestableListView/src/main/java/com/tf/library/nestablelistview/NestableListView.java)

Comment: So practically rewriting a ListView?